# Is literal string indexing standard C?

Tags: c, string, indexing

I stumbled upon code containing something like:

```
char c = "abc"[1];
```

and it compiles and runs fine with gcc! `c` will be `'b'` after this expression.

Is this standard to index literal strings or is it mere luck that it works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it is, a string literal is of array type.  It is converted to a pointer to `char` in the expression and is like an any pointer to `char`.

```
char c = "abc"[1];
```

and

```
char *p = "abc";
char c = p[1];
```

are equivalent.

Comment: yep, now that you put it this way I see it too ;). It just look odd... One more comment: It should be `const char *p = "abc"` in order to be equivalent, right?

Comment: The "abc" is not stored in the first case. Just the 'b', so no.

Comment: @steffen no, in C a string literal when evaluated is converted to a `char *` and not to a `const char *p`.

Comment: @ouah, this isn't true. string literals are constant, and on most systems you will crash if you try to write to them

Comment: @TomTanner string literals are `const char[n+1]` in C++ but in C they are `char[n+1]` and required to be non-modifiable. This is for historical reasons.

Comment: ahh, thanks for clarifying. I'm rather a C++ programmer, that's probably why I missed the `const`

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely standard. A string is actually a piece of syntactic sugar to a pointer to an array of characters, and any pointer can use subscript notation.

In fact, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a + b)` which in turn is equivalent to `*(b + a)`, which leads you to the slightly surprising result that `a[b]` is equivalent to `b[a]`, which is why in some code (especially, but sadly not exclusively, in obfuscated code competitions), this sort of thing:

```
char c = 1["abc"];
```

can occur.

Comment: Lol, never seen this and never thought about it. Seems legit, though :)

Comment: :D I made this a "coffee break quiz" for our office.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard because a string defined by "" is converted to a char* (char pointer) which you can index. The target of that pointer is always 1 char which is b in your case.