# Index operator bound to a string literal

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-literals, c89

So I decided to experiment, completely out of randomness.
And I found this:

```
"Hello World"[1]
```

Actually working on a first view, resulting in `'e'`
even though:

- I haven't encounter this anywhere until happened to be in my code
- Seems semantically controversial (or at least quite suspicious)
- Could not find any information on the internet, regarding this positive string literal array indexing (probably searching in the wrong context?)

  ---

Is this actually allowed, confronting the "standards" with guaranteed well-defined behavior ?

Comment: Completely legal, completely standard, old news.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is literal string indexing standard C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503248/is-literal-string-indexing-standard-c)

Comment: Note this is standard in many other languages,

Comment: I think S/O needs improvements concerning the questions searcher.

Comment: No search engine can foresee the creativeness of askers on SO. It's all a matter of search phrase and memory (I had in mind there were such questions (sic! plural!).

Comment: Me either. I was closely certain that there is such question already. However, I could not find it so..

Comment: See also [question 6.11](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/q6.11.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: When converting to decimal or hexadecimal strings it's not uncommon to see things like `*p++ = "0123456789"[n%10]` or `*p++ = "0123456789abcdef"[n%16]`.

Comment: @Malina Yeah the searcher is terrible. Using google with "site:stackoverflow.com" does better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is semantically correct.  `"Hello World"[1]` is equivalent to `*("Hello World" + 1)`. In this expression the string `"Hello World"` will be converted to pointer to its first element. Therefore, `("Hello World" + 1)` is the address of second element of string `"Hello World"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Hello World"[1]
```

is perfectly valid. A string literal is of type array of `N` characters. The type of `"Hello World"` is an array of 12 `char` (i.e., `char[12]`).